# pdf thumbnail imagemagick php not working

Tags: php, imagemagick, ghostscript

I am using imagemagick and ghostscript in my windows pc running php5 in apache.

I tried

```
<?php
$im = new imagick('test.pdf[0]');
$im->setImageFormat( "jpg" );
header( "Content-Type: image/jpeg" );
echo $im;
?>
```

and found its not working.

My php info file shows imagick working...

[image]

I am trying to generate a thumbnail without saving it in the server hard drive...

Comment: What exactly is happening? Is there an error of some kind or just a blank page?

Comment: no.. nothing is getting displayed...

Comment: I am trying to generate a thumbnail without saving it in the server hard drive... is that possible??

Comment: Does your file really have `[0]` at the end of its filename?

Comment: Is PHP set to display all errors?
Put this after `<?php` and check if any errors are shown: `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT | E_NOTICE);`

@ceejayoz it's a special ImageMagick way to tell it only to take the first page of the PDF :)

Comment: @ceejayoz, my filename is test.pdf and used [0] for getting thumbnail of first page

Comment: @stormbreaker, nothing is getting displayed, u can see my code here: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/386973/

Comment: Do you have Imagemagick itself installed? What I hear is that the php extension requires it. Also did you test with another pdf file? I'm guessing here, but it might lead you to the answer.

Comment: @stormbreaker, its already installed and its working for another syntax, which convert pdf into jpg and saves it in my hard drive.. I am looking for a solution which displays image without saving in the folder, like my syntax given...

Comment: I tested your code and it works just fine on my server. I'm running the latest version of imagick, maybe you can try updating. Can you upload it to your server and give us a link?

Comment: hi @stormbreaker, thanks.. but i am running it in my localhost.. I am running apache in my vista.. In my IMDisplay, it is saying imagemagick version 6.6.9-8 2011-05-04 Q16. Here is my php library file http://www.4shared.com/file/ZXdixJjT/php_imagick.html. Any more information will be given if you want..

Comment: hi @stormbreaker, the code here: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/387570/ works fine for me, which creates an image in my folder. But I want to display image without saving it in my hard drive.

Comment: It's definitely something wrong with the php extension for imagick, but I'm out of ideas.
Try it on a different PC maybe re-download the extension and imagemagick and check if it's the same way. Your code works with me so it must be a bug or php misconfiguration.

Comment: hi @stormbreaker, can you give me the download link for the right one for me pls... I am running Apache/2.2.17 (Win32) PHP/5.3.0

Comment: I tested on a linux virtual machine. While looking for windows installation instructions i found a very interesting comment. The fix was to use the full path to the file. So `$im = new imagick('test.pdf[0]');` becomes `$im = new imagick(realpath('test.pdf').'[0]');`

Try this way :)

Comment: WOW... GR8... really works for me.. Thank you so much @stormbreaker... :) .. Can you post this as answer so that I can accept..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're outputting the imagick OBJECT, not the image you're dealing with. To output as a .jpg, you'd need to do

```
echo $im->getImageBlob();
```

Comment: There may be other errors, but this is definitely an issue. +1.

Comment: and @ceejayoz check this out: http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.examples-1.php
Also there is a php magic method that allows you to do such things with classes. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php see `__toString`